# Multiplayer with Phyrexian Swarmlord

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-multiplayer

[Phyrexian Swarmlord](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPhyrexian%20Swarmlord%5d)'s last ability is that you create infect tokens based on the number of poison counters on your opponents. Let's say I'm playing a 1v1v1 and I have him on the battlefield with opponent A having 2 poison counters and opponent B having 9, and I proliferate. If I choose player B's poison counters as part of my proliferate that player loses from having 10 poison counters, but as the game continues, would I still get 10 tokens from them where the player lost with that many counters on them? Or should I exclude them from proliferate as long as possible to continue getting 9 infect tokens because they need to be alive in the game to get the tokens?

Comment: You could Donate a Platinum Angel :)

Answer (score 6):

You will not get to count the counters from the player who has lost.

When a player loses the game in multiplayer, that player leaves the game, which means they are not in any way a part of the game. They are no longer an opponent, they no longer have poison counters, they do not exist at all as far as the game is concerned.

> 800.4. Unlike two-player games, multiplayer games can continue after one or more players have **left the game**.

And

> 102.1. A player is one of the people **in the game**.
>
> 102.3. In a multiplayer game between teams, a player's teammates are the other players on their team, and the player's opponents are all **players** not on their team.

So a person who has left the game is not "in the game", which means they are not "a player", and "an opponent" must be "a player".

Comment: Trying to find a good way to explain why 800.4h does not apply here... "If an effect requires information about a specific player, the effect uses the current information about that player if they are still in the game; otherwise, the effect uses the last known information about that player before they left the game."

Comment: The effect doesn't require about that **specific** player. It just needs information about your opponents in general. I think that rule is for covering situations like one where you choose a player, and then an effect on that card cares about some information about that player after that player leaves the game.

Answer (score 0):

If your opponent loses the game because of having 10 or more poison counters, they *leave the game* and Phyrexian Swarmlord doesn't 'detect' them anymore; you won't get Insect tokens from them. So if your goals is to create many tokens, it's best to keep them alive and not target them while proliferating.